# Updating the reference count when moving a file?

Tags: memory, memory-management, inode

If I move a file on the same partition, while I am moving, should I update the reference count of the i-node to two (since I am first copying) and then decrement it to 1 again (when I delete the directory entry) ?

Or the reference count is untouched during moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

When a file is "moved", what's really happening is that the reference to the inode in the file naming layer is being changed, that's it.  In fact, the file is not copied.

Realize that the file naming layer is purely for your convenience.  The file system itself really only cares about the inodes.  Even directories are, generally, a fiction of the file naming layer.  (It is true that some file systems actually organize directories hierarchically at the file system layer, but this would not be true of ext2 and ext3, for instance).

While it is technically true that for an extremely brief period there are either no references or two references to the file in the naming layer, this is really an atomic transaction from the point of view of the system call into the kernel that is being made, so it effectively will not matter and will not be a race condition for you.

Comment: Thanks, can you be more precise on this: the reference of the inode is changed if the file is kept in the same folder, if I move a file to another folder then I must remove the dir entry and add the dir entry in a new directory. During this process, will I update the reference count of the inode? Also, that is an atomic operation OS wise, but it won't be hardware wise, right?

Comment: The only thing that "moves" is the file name.  The actual file (the inode) does not move or change.  The only time that it would is if you are moving the file to another partition.  Try this experiment:  Use `ls -i` to view the inodes of files in a directory.  Use `mv` to move one of them to another directory and try `ls -i` on that file in the new directory.  You will see that the inode number has *not* changed.

Comment: @nick: depending on the file system implementation, there may be a short period during which the inode reference count of the source file may be incremented.  The guarantee is that the inode associated with the destination filename is replaced atomically if it already existed before the call.